# Deploy to Azure from TFS failed on Get-AzureDeployment

Tags: powershell, azure, tfs

I have a problem
We deploy to Azure from TFS server and need to change subscription.
I downloaded new publishsettings from server and tried to modify build definition.
But got the error - Get-AzureDeployment : Value cannot be null. Parameter name: subscriptionId

I copied powershell command from TFS log and executed it at server from console - all works fine.
Any ideas, why it doesn't work from build definition?

Comment: Looks like your subscription ID is not going through.

Comment: I would move to RM rather than Team Build for deployments...

Comment: @MrHinsh script write subscription id on execute, it's correct.
I just can't understand difference between executing the same command from build definition and powershell console. From console it work, but from build definition fails.

Comment: The only thing that I can think of is that he ID is not passed in the build...

Comment: @MrHinsh I found a solution. Actually, it's problem only of TFS build. Other CI system can work with this script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.
For using TFS build you always need link your cloud service with source control.
But TeamCity and script works fine, without linking.